# Xcode simulator 10.5-inch table row wrong position

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Tell me is that bug or not? I've created many UITableView's in my developer life and never seen this before.

I have custom `UITableViewCell` with `UILabel` and `UIButton` created in Storyboard.

```
class MyCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var title: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    var row: Int? {
        didSet {
            guard let row = row else { return }

            title.text = "row number: \(row)"
            button.tag = row
        }
    }

    @IBAction func onCellClick(_ sender: UIView) {
        print(sender.tag)
    }
}
```

And my `UITableViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController {

}

extension ViewController {
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 30
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MyCell
        cell.row = indexPath.row
        return cell
    }
}
```

The button is aligned to full size of a `contentView` of the cell.

If i run this code on any device and simulator everything works without any problem. The problem appears when I run this code on 10.5-inch simulator. When I am clicking on cell button `print(sender.tag)` printing me TWO tag values: first one proper that I clicked on AND second one **last visible cell** on screen.

I discovered when I set even 1 px offset to button size everything works like a charm! Why is so big problem when I stretch button to contentView size? Can you explain it? I appreciate every idea, comment and explanation!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Xcode 9.4.1 works fine. Please update Xcode if you have older version and check again.

Comment: That's true! I had Xcode version 9.2 and that was the problem - something bugged. Updated Xcode works well. Thanks Apple and thanks @milczi!